# MySql 5.6 keeps crashing

Tags: mysql

I upgraded MySQL and now it crashes 3-4 times a day.

I have WHM set to monitor this service, so it does recover, but I experience intermitteant down time due to this.

I performed a MySQL_Upgrade.

Here is a sampling of the error log:

```
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 579981897
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 579981897
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150821 23:25:59 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150821 23:25:59 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-21 23:25:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 581241150
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 581282693
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 581282693
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-22 02:36:21 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 02:36:56 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 02:37:23 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 11:27:54 13544 [Warning] IP address '122.224.6.150' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150822 20:54:11 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 20:54:11 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 20:54:11 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 589358444 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 20:54:12 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 20:54:12 15947 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 589358444
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150822 20:54:13 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 20:54:13 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 20:54:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 589358444 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 589358444
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-22 21:28:15 15983 [Warning] IP address '221.229.162.143' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150822 23:04:56 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 23:04:56 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 23:04:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 590358682
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 590373690
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 590373690
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-23 02:42:47 19131 [Warning] IP address '221.229.162.143' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to '45.34.1.137'.
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Note] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' has the following IP addresses:
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Note]  - 199.15.112.8
2015-08-23 20:42:45 19131 [Warning] IP address '60.191.129.138' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-23 20:54:08 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 599201345 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/{hostname}.pid ended
150823 20:57:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2015-08-23 20:57:34 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 599201345 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 599201345
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Here is a screenshot of the WHM service status page:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think this is best suited on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: How much Ram do you have on your box and what are your cache and your buffer settings?  Is this a dedicated server?  are you running anything else on that server?

Comment: I am not sure how to find that info in WHM.  I uploaded a screenshot of the service status page.  This is a VPS with GoDaddy (no opinions please), running 5 WordPress websites and running 15-20 email addresses with cPanel.